# Calling Fields from arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, field

I have been working on programming some motors for an Arduino project and wondered if anyone could help me with this.

I am effectively trying to specify `HIGH`/`LOW` attributes to things in the array.

Here is what I am wanting to implement into the array.

```
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH); // Motor 2
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH); // Motor 2
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(in5, HIGH); // Motor 3
  digitalWrite(in6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in7, HIGH); // Motor 4
  digitalWrite(in8, LOW);
```

I have managed to get the array to work by using the `LOW` tag, however this tells the motors to not spin at all.

I would like to be able to set them to these values. 
In my code, the array I am wanting to edit uses the `motors`, `mtrPin` and `motorPin` attributes.

[You can see it for reference here.](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/fFQKRTjhDrb-motor-initial-turn/editel)

```
// Array of PWM's
int pwmPin = 0;
uint8_t pwms[] = {3,5,6,11};
byte numberPwms = 4;

// Array for motors channels
int mtrPin = 0;
uint8_t motors[] = {4,2,8,7,12,13,9,10};
byte motorPin = 8;

void setup()
{

  for (pwmPin = 0; pwmPin < numberPwms; pwmPin++){
      for (mtrPin = 0; mtrPin < motorPin; mtrPin++){
            pinMode(motors[mtrPin], OUTPUT);
        pinMode(pwms[pwmPin], OUTPUT);
        };
    }; 
}

void motorLoop(){
// setting the direction to turn and speed

//  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH); // Motor 2
//  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);  
//  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH); // Motor 2
//  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);  
//  digitalWrite(in5, HIGH); // Motor 3
//  digitalWrite(in6, LOW);
//  digitalWrite(in7, HIGH); // Motor 4
//  digitalWrite(in8, LOW);

// Set the speed for the Motors

  for(int pwmPin = 0; pwmPin < numberPwms; pwmPin++){
      for (mtrPin = 0; mtrPin < motorPin; mtrPin++){
            pinMode(motors[mtrPin], LOW);
        analogWrite(pwms[pwmPin], 200);
      };
   };  
};

void loop()
{
  motorLoop();
  delay(500);

}
```

Comment: Your tinkercad link says it expired. Try to include all the code we need in this question. I don't think we can answer it without seeing the digitalWrite and pinMode functions.

Comment: there is no pinMode(,LOW). don't use pinMode if you use analogWrite. your code doesn't make sense. read it as you would be the MCU. here I do this, here this...

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 motors with 2 pins each, an **array** of 8 elements is wrong.
Learn about `struct` or immediately go to c++ `class`

```
struct MotorPins {
 const byte DIR;
 const byte ON;
 const byte PWM; } motors[] = {
//DIR  ON PWM 
  {4,  2,  3 },
  {8,  7,  5 },
  {12, 13, 6 },
  {9,  10, 11}
};   

const byte mCount = sizeof(motors)/sizeof(motors[0]); // use in a classic for-loop

void setup (){
  for (MotorPins mp: motors) {
    pinMode(mp.DIR, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(mp.ON , OUTPUT);
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Hi Thankyou for you brilliant comment! after adapting it and looking into structs I now have a better understanding of what they are and how they work! :D I have managed to get all the motors to spin correctly but kept getting C++98 errors on TinkerCAD but worked fine with my arduino. I guess they're a bit out of data with the C++ versions :P Thanks again! I've just got one last question however. How would I be able to choose a specific motor from the code and set whether they be HIGH or LOW?

Comment: `for (MotorPins mp: motors)` this for_each construct was written `for (int i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {MotorPins mp = motors[i]; ... }` and if you know your motors by their index (0 .. 3) you can easily address them separately. Alternatively, you can work with 4 separate variables instead (or additionally to) of an array of 4.
Best you learn about references (or pointers) to  use both in parallel...